# JPA hibernate foreign key not set in entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am performing a parent child save using CASCADE.PERSIST

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent extends AbstractAuditingEntity{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id",nullable = false)
    private List<Child> children;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child extends AbstractAuditingEntity{

    @Column(name = "parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long parentId;

}
```

When I save the parent ,the child also gets saved along with the foreign key.

```
parent = parentRepository.save(parent);
```

But the entity that is returned from the repository does not have the foriegn key set in the child.

*child.getParentId()* is null .

Is there anyway I can get it done ?

---

Tried setting the parent in the child but same problem exists

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child extends AbstractAuditingEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id",nullable = false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Queue queue;
}
```

Though this is a not a critical issue ( i can set it manually from the parent ) - Just wanted to be sure If I am doing it right.

Comment: 1. We need a complete minimal example to understand what you're doing (transaction boundaries, etc.). 2. You shouldn't have a prentId field in Child in the first place. Remove it, or replace it by a field of type Parent, and make the association a proper bidirectional OneToMany association, as explained in the manual.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Bidirectional association also has same issue .Updated the question

Comment: That's not how a bidirectional association is mapped. And you still haven't posted a complete minimal example, so I can only guess that you're expecting, in the same transaction, that Hibernate populates the many side. It won't. As specified.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes this is happening in the same transaction. I will try to get the bidirectional association corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by JB Nizet , the bidrectional mapping was incorrect.

This has been corrected as per the below link and it worked fine

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic happen on save. That means if you don't set parentId then this field is null. You have to set this on your own.

When you read the data using find or with a query then the field will be set by JPA.

Comment: The issue was resolved as per the suggestion given by JB Nizet .

Comment: But this is often not the best solution because this can lead to a n+1 problem.

Comment: True. For this service, the cost of n+1 problem is not a concern.  Probably for future services , i plan to take care of the n+1 problem.

Comment: Btw. the solution for your problem is my answer because when creating an object you always have to take care of filling all the fields. There is no magic in JPA